# add a associated value in ruby on rails from independent page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im beginner of ruby on rails. i have brand - products list.

Brand,

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 2 }
end
```

Product,

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

products.controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token


  def edit
     @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def update
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.update(product_params)
    redirect_to brand_path(@brand)
  end

  def create
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    @product = @brand.products.create(product_params)
    redirect_to brand_path(@brand)
  end

  def destroy
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    @product = @brand.products.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to brand_path(@brand)
  end

  def update
    @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    @product = @brand.products.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
  end

  helper_method :update

  private
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name)
    end



end
```

the new.html.erb,

```
    <h1> Add a new product </h1>

<%= form_with model: @brand, local: true do |form| %>

<p>
  <%= form.label :title,"Product name" %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
</p>


  <p>
    <%= form.label :title,"Select a Brand" %><br>
    <%= form.collection_select(:brand, Brand.all, :id, :title) { @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id]) } %>

  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit "Save Product", :onclick => "create" %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :brands do
    resources :products
  end
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

when i cliked the button i get error, 
No route matches [POST] "/brands/%23%3CBrand::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f5e30d87490%3E/products/new"

Rails.root: /home/berkay/e-ticaret

SO, how can i save this product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change that one

```
<%= form_with model: @brand, local: true do |form| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_with(model: @product, url: [@brand, @product]) %>
```

Also add

`@brand = Brand.find(a_brand_id)`

inside your `new` method of `ProductsController` class. So, rails is going to know which brand is parent of that product.

UPDATE

I've created a dummy project which is going to work as you expected.

**products/_form.html.erb** partial for product

```
<%= form_with(model: product, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">

    <%= form.label :title, "Select a Brand" %><br>
    <%= form.collection_select(:brand_id, Brand.all, :id, :title, {selected: @brand.id})  %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products
  resources :brands
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController


  # GET /products/new
  def new
    if params[:brand_id]
      @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    end
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def edit
    @brand = @product.brand
  end 

   ...

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :brand_id)
  end
end
```

I've also added a hotlink to create a  product for a given brand

**brands/show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @brand.title %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_brand_path(@brand) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', brands_path %> |
<%= link_to 'Create Products', new_product_path(brand_id: @brand.id) %>
```

[image: Brand page]

[image: Create product]
[image: Type and submit]
[image: Success]

Comment: Showing /home/berkay/e-ticaret/app/views/products/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:
undefined method `products_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f5e30c25ef8>:0x00007f5e30c24620>

<%= form_with model: @product, local: true do |form| %>

Comment: could you please add contents of your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: i added the routes.rb

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I've just realized that it is a nested form.

Comment: brand must be selected in combobox. so we dont know yet and  ı get the error

Comment: Couldn't find Brand with 'id'=#<Brand::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fa990876cc0>

Comment: Iif it is going to be revealed after combobox selection, then you need to update your routes file too. if you run `rake routes` on console, you'll see something like `new_brand_product` path which is mapped to `/brands/:brand_id/products/new`.

Comment: my url: http://localhost:3000/brands/%23%3CBrand::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005644eeaf32a8%3E/products/new

how can i update routes files ?

Answer (score 0):

When using nested routes you would have to write

```
 form_with model: [@brand, @product]
```

it will use the array to compose the path and the last item will be actually edited.

Your `new` action should best be changed as follows:

```
def new 
  @brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id)
  @product = @brand.products.build  
end
```

Comment: Couldn't find Brand with 'id'=#<Brand::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fa990876cc0> 
because, i want to select brand using combobox.

Comment: Which url are you visiting? Because `params[:brand_id]` seems to be a relation???

Comment: url: http://localhost:3000/brands/%23%3CBrand::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005644eeaf32a8%3E/products/new

Comment: How do you build that url? It should look like this: `localhost:3000/brands/:brand_id/products_new` and instead of a `:brand_id` rails expects a single brand id (aka a number).

Comment: how can i build that without brand_id ? because i want to page like, enter product name and select brand name (drop down list) and save it. and i dont know how can i find the brand_id which is selected from dropdown list.

Comment: That would be easier without using nested routes. Just select the brand-id in the form. That is a lot easier. But checking access-rights is harder, e.g. when not everyone has access to the same brand.