# how to set id from independent page using dropdown list ? or how can i save the belongs_to, has_many value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm beginner in ruby on rails. I want to create Brand - Product list. I would like to add product names and brand name (should be selected in dropdown list) from an independent page.  Every product has a name and a brand Id. ı will set the brand name which is selected from drop down list to a variable. after that, ı will add the product name the user have written in independent page and the brand Id to product table.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'add_product/index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :brands do
    resources :products
  end
  root 'welcome#index'

end
```

.._create_brands.rb

```
class CreateBrands < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :brands do |t|
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

.._create_products.rb

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :brand, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

brand.rb

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 2 }
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

add_product/index.html.erb  (add_product has view and controller)

```
<h1>Add a new product</h1>
<%= form_with(model: @product) do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :name,"Product name: " %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<%= f.collection_select(:brand_id, Brand.all, :id, :title) %>
<p>

    <%= f.submit "Add a product" %>

</p>
<% end %>
```

add_product_controller.rb

```
class AddProductController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
   @product = Product.new
  end

   def create
     @product = Product.new(product_params)
     if @product.save
        redirect_to @product
     else
        render :new
     end
   end

   private
     def product_params
       params.require(:product).permit(:name,:brand_id)
     end

end
```

when i run the rails routes in console,

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                        welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                                                                 welcome#index
                    add_product_index GET    /add_product/index(.:format)                                                             add_product#index
                       brand_products GET    /brands/:brand_id/products(.:format)                                                     products#index
                                      POST   /brands/:brand_id/products(.:format)                                                     products#create
                    new_brand_product GET    /brands/:brand_id/products/new(.:format)                                                 products#new
                   edit_brand_product GET    /brands/:brand_id/products/:id/edit(.:format)                                            products#edit
                        brand_product GET    /brands/:brand_id/products/:id(.:format)                                                 products#show
                                      PATCH  /brands/:brand_id/products/:id(.:format)                                                 products#update
                                      PUT    /brands/:brand_id/products/:id(.:format)                                                 products#update
                                      DELETE /brands/:brand_id/products/:id(.:format)                                                 products#destroy
                               brands GET    /brands(.:format)                                                                        brands#index
                                      POST   /brands(.:format)                                                                        brands#create
                            new_brand GET    /brands/new(.:format)                                                                    brands#new
                           edit_brand GET    /brands/:id/edit(.:format)                                                               brands#edit
                                brand GET    /brands/:id(.:format)                                                                    brands#show
                                      PATCH  /brands/:id(.:format)                                                                    brands#update
                                      PUT    /brands/:id(.:format)                                                                    brands#update
                                      DELETE /brands/:id(.:format)                                                                    brands#destroy
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        welcome#index
```

[independent page picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvSkp.png)

if i go to brans and clicked the show i can add product with only name. but i want to add a product from independent page. so how can i do it? Can i set brand_id value from dropdownlist? than can i save product name and brand id?

Comment: Welcome. Yes, assuming you have a brand you can send the brand_id value from a dropdown list and then create a product with name and brand_id. So there are a few options.
1. Create Brand in brands/new and have nested attributes for its products (New Brand/New Products)
2. in Brands/show create Its child Products (Send the hidden field brand_id for each product, I guess you are doing this already)
3. In an Independent page Create a form for Product and pass the brand_id to it by a dropdown which populates Brands and the user selects one) - (Existing brand, new products).

Comment: Check the `add_product/index.html.erb` file. It already does what you are asking for. I would also suggest you to try things out and go through some basic tutorials to get well versed with associations and their implication on forms etc.

Comment: You can look into `accepts_nested_attributes_for` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: are you working on same project? -)) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59839659/add-a-associated-value-in-ruby-on-rails-from-independent-page/59839743#59839743